# Docker build fails with "required feature is not installed" when running in a Windows 10 VM

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, docker, hyper-v, xen

I have installed Docker Desktop for Windows on a Windows 10 Pro VM. The host is a Xen hypervisor running Debian 11.

Within the Windows VM, I need to build and use a Docker image using Windows container mode. When building the image, I get this error:

```
hcs::CreateComputeSystem ...: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
```

I searched around for solutions to this error and it seems it has to do with virtualization feature(s) not being available in the Windows 10 VM. I've enabled everything I could find, but it's still not working

On DOM0 (Debian), using xen 4.14.5, I have updated the Windows 10 VM config to allow nested virtualization [per these instructions](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Nested_Virtualization_in_Xen#How_to_use_nested) and re-created the VM:

```
hap = 1
nestedhvm = 1
```

Inside the Windows 10 Pro VM, I check that the features are enabled:

```
PS> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName "Microsoft-Hyper-V*" -Online
... everything Enabled ...
PS> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName "Containers" -Online
... Enabled ...
```

When looking at the computer properties [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49013155/1566525), I see some blanks, which others in that comment thread observed, but there was no conclusion.

```
PS> Get-ComputerInfo -property "HyperV*"
HyperVisorPresent                                 : True
HyperVRequirementDataExecutionPreventionAvailable :
HyperVRequirementSecondLevelAddressTranslation    :
HyperVRequirementVirtualizationFirmwareEnabled    :
HyperVRequirementVMMonitorModeExtensions          :
```

Other notes:

- Docker has a document [Run Docker Desktop for Windows in a VM or VDI environment](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/vm-vdi/) which points to nested virtualization, but it doesn't give instructions for Xen (only VMware and Hyper-V host)

Comment: I’m not saying this is impossible, but there is only one supported way to nest the Hyper-V hypervisor: Inside Hyper-V. // Maybe process isolation mode is enough for you? A VM would not be used in that case. Dunno if that’s possible with `docker build`.

Comment: Not ideal since the image uses a different Windows version than the one running docker. (If I use `docker build --isolation=process` it just gives an error "The container operating system does not match the host operating system"

Comment: Based on [this](https://lore.kernel.org/xen-devel/001401d77de6$34ff5de0$9efe19a0$@comcast.net/T/) and [this](https://xcp-ng.org/forum/topic/4643/nested-virtualization-of-windows-hyper-v-on-xcp-ng), seems like you're right... this is a dead end for now. Xen nested virtualization does not work for Hyper-V in the DomU.